# .htaccess How to routing from /a/b/c.php to /a/c.api

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am very newbie on .htaccess and such a things
i really need to route my files 
when accessed :

> http://blabla/api/bla.api

but the real file source is

> http://blabla/api/files/test/test.php

if i use Fat-Free-Framework, that might be possible.
but how to implements it on .htaccess ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think that you're mixing up some stuff ...

.htaccess file cannot real route an uri . You can redirect, rewrite, ... but real routing is not an option, you just make your URI 'nicer' to read

A router (usually) will talk to controller witch will fetch, calculate, do stuff and pass the result to a view that will generate your page with the info passed from controller.

But anyway, [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049) are some code snippets for redirecting with .htaccess or/and follow [this tutorial](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file) for .htaccess redirects and easy php example that gives you more power to supports more complex logic.